# How do you make structural changes to Azure SQL Server DBs when you don't have access via SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, azure

We're no longer allowed to have access to UAT/PROD environments via SSMS at my organization. The way our deployment process works is tied to git pushes. So when you push to the DEV branch, the DEV web code and DB is updated, likewise when pushing to the QA branch and the UAT branch.

The problem is when there is a structural change to the DB, very often the deployment fails with the error `data loss may occur`. In the past, with on-prem solutions, when we would publish the DB, if we encountered the `data loss may occur` error we could uncheck `Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur` in Visual Studio and the deployment would work. We never incurred any data loss either. Since this option is no longer available, it was suggested we use pre and post deployment scripts.

What do I need to put in the pre and post deployment scripts to prevent the data loss error? Our Visual Studio DB Project already contains all the table/view/SP/function definitions.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183626/granularity-of-block-incremental-deployment-if-data-loss-might-occur) might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's really depending on the nature of changes you are facing but an example could be a schema change on a table.

You can do this:

- Rename the existing table in a pre-deployment script.
- With the existing table missing the table in focus will be created as per the new schema definition.
- In a post-deployment script copy from the renamed original table to the new version.

Depending on the nature of the target you may of course need to take care of dropping and recreating foreign key constraints.

Beware of the option 'drop objects not in source'.